# Linq query on XML only returns first element

Tags: vb.net, linq

Ok, I've racked my brain on this and just cant get it to work so any help is appreciated. When the below query runs it will return the first "AccessItem" as long as the name attribute matches. If I move that same accessitem to be the second AccessItem then nothing is returned. Obviously I only want the "AccessItem"(s) with the name Attribute that match to be returned.

```
<payload>
    <Product>
        <Configuration>
            <InternetTimeSettings>
                <Enabled>False</Enabled>
                <NISTServers>time-c.nist.gov,nist.time.nosc.us,wwv.nist.gov</NISTServers>
                <GMTOffset>-5</GMTOffset>
                <ObserveDaylightSaving>True</ObserveDaylightSaving>
            </InternetTimeSettings>
            <LogEntryTimeStamps>
            </LogEntryTimeStamps>
            <EventTimeStamps>
            </EventTimeStamps>
        </Configuration>
        <UserAccess>
            <AccessItem name="Administration" users="Admin" personas="Administrators" groups=""/>
            <AccessItem name="Add Reports" users="Admin" personas="Administrators" groups=""/>
            <AccessItem name="Edit Reports" users="Admin" personas="Administrators" groups=""/>
            <AccessItem name="Delete Reports" users="Admin" personas="Administrators" groups=""/>
        </UserAccess>
    </Product>
</payload>



Dim xEL As XElement
xEL = XElement.Parse(//RefToAboveXML\\)
Dim TS As New UserAccessProperty
Dim TS As String = AccessItemName
Dim Query = From el In xEL.Elements("Product").Elements("UserAccess") Where el.Element("AccessItem").Attribute("name") = AccessItemName Select el
If Query.Count > 0 Then
    For Each elm As XElement In Query
            cUserAccess = elm
                TS.Users = elm.Element("AccessItem").Attribute("users").Value
                TS.Personas = elm.Element("AccessItem").Attribute("personas").Value
                TS.Groups = elm.Element("AccessItem").Attribute("groups").Value
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your LINQ to select `<AccessItem>`s instead of `<UserAccess>` :

```
Dim Query = From el In xEL.Elements("Product").
                           Elements("UserAccess").
                           Elements("AccessItem")  '<- select <AccessItem>'
            Where el.Attribute("name") = AccessItemName '<- filter only those with specific name attribute value'
            Select el
If Query.Count > 0 Then
    For Each elm As XElement In Query
        TS.Users = elm.Attribute("users").Value
        TS.Personas = elm.Attribute("personas").Value
        TS.Groups = elm.Attribute("groups").Value
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thank you... not sure how I missed it :( but this now works. :)